# PHP: how to convert mb string to its UTF escape sequence

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I would like to convert a mb string to UTF escape sequence.

> Hello

to

> \u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f

How to do such a thing?

Comment: good question but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `json_encode("русский")` and you get  `"\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439"` for English not requer encode to utf-8 escaped string. Для русского обязательно.